# Функция на Python. Помогите разобраться с кодом

Tags: python-3.x

Есть функция на Python. В ней есть строка, я не могу понять, что она делает и как она работает.

Строка - name_currency, course_currency = currencies[currency]. Код ниже в картинке.

Подскажите, как называется этот приём, что он делает?

[image: Пример кода]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

```
name_currency, course_currency = currencies[currency]
```

`currencies` - это *словарь*, из него берётся элемент по *ключу* `currency`. При этом элементы этого словаря - *кортежи*. С помощью такого присваивания `name_currency, course_currency = ...` *кортеж* из двух элементов *распаковывается* в две отдельные переменные.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ! Пойду читать про распаковку кортежей))